# Can Mystique become the Hulk if she shapeshifts into Bruce Banner?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I know that she can't acquire another mutant's powers by becoming them, but what about someone like Bruce Banner? [He is not a mutant, and neither is the Hulk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42960/is-the-hulk-technically-a-mutant). Banner's "power" is practically an infection or a virus. So could Mystique become Banner, then get angry to become the Hulk? **Using the version of her that can change her mass.**

**Or you can think about it like this:** If Bruce Banner gets mad, and starts becoming the Hulk, at what point in the transformation would Mystique no longer be able to become the Hulk/Banner? Sometimes the transformation takes a while if he's fighting it.

**Note:** I don't see how this is duplicate to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56952/how-does-mystique-change-height) as I am ignoring that question by **assuming that she can change mass** and asking another question on top of it. If you read the old version of the post I had the same thing about **using the version of her that can change mass**, it was just not bold.

Comment: also, mystique doesnt exist in the [tag:marvel-cinematic-universe]

Comment: That question has been asked and they decided that she can look like the Hulk but not have his powers, I am thinking of this as a way for her to have his powers. Also, she does exist, because the X-Men exist, we just haven't seen her. Or have we? She can look like anyone. @phantom42

Comment: None of the X-Men films are in the MCU.

Comment: Oh cool thanks @RogueJedi! I am new to this community

Comment: This question was closed because the answer exists in several other questions on the site. Before attempting to reopen it please rewrite it to find a question not already discussed at length in previous Mystique answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Mystique only copies appearance. She doesn't copy stuff inside people's bodies or their properties.

- She can't become strong like Adamantium or Colossus's skin
- She can't copy powers/DNA
- She can't copy thoughts

She wouldn't be able to copy the changes to Banner's DNA/molecular structure due to the Gamma radiation.

To boot, she probably [wouldn't be able to change her mass](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/56960/31178) enough to change directly into the Hulk, unless it's after her bonus-power "event".

However, even if she were able to appear just like Hulk, she wouldn't gain his Gamma-enhanced strength.

Comment: Does she have enough mass to become the hulk anyway? Apparently mass must not be an issue for her I guess, since she did shape shift into a small child in the movie.